# Is classifying documents according to their topic useful for any application?

Tags: classification, application, topic-models

Suppose that we have digitized document images; we pass this documents through OCR and we get text text documents, that we classify according to their topics in different classes such as payroll, various bills, information letters ...

Is this classification useful for in application for information extraction ? How ? Examples

Remember, the documents are a digitized document images (like invoices etc). Can you please tell me for what it can be useful (in the context of information extraction) to classify this documents based on the text they contains ?

Comment: You should not cross-post without linking. This wastes the time of the people trying to help you. http://metaoptimize.com/qa/questions/12024/is-classifying-documents-according-to-their-topic-useful-for-any-application

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course! This has actually been studied pretty extensively and is called document/text classification/categorization. All four combinations seem to mean pretty much the same thing.

It's definitely useful for information retrieval (it'd be nice to search just invoices or something), and the ability to organize documents is also handy. Spam detection is a very reduced version of this task for email, though you can imagine that it'd be nice to have a "virtual secretary" that sorts your email more thoroughly.  There are products which analyze emails, documents, and presentations to determine which ones need to be disclosed or retained (for regulatory purposes or in response to a subpoena) and which can safely be deleted. For example, certain types of communications with investors need to be retained, while emails about (say) birthdays or free cake in the breakroom do not.

This is all application dependent though, and might be veering off-topic for Cross Validated.

One might also use a document classification to "condition" other processing based on the document's category. For example, the word 'net' has many meanings: an open-meshed material (e.g., for catching fish), a sports goal (e.g., basketball or hockey), a computer network, or even money remaining after expenses.  If you were doing machine translation, you might want to condition your language + translation models based on the document's category. For example, for english-spanish translation P(en='net', es='neto' | financial document) is probably much larger than P(en='net', es='red' | financial documents). Off the top of my head, I can't think of any system that aggressively does this, but there are many domain-specific translation systems and one could certainly merge them like this.

In a similar vein, you could use document type to disambiguate terms even if you're not translating. For example, the account number on an incoming invoice has a different meaning than the account number on an outgoing invoice/incoming payment/service request. In the first case, you probably want to route that document to accounts payable so that they can verify the transaction, take money from that department's budget, and cut a check. In the other cases, you might instead want to credit or debit a customer's account or set up an appointment.

In my view, document categorization has two major roles: 1) organizing a collection of documents, for whatever purpose and 2) providing better background or contextual information for other tasks.

Comment: Well, I'm not interested in email spam detection or language translation. You didn't said much about information extraction (which is what I'm interested in) from the documents that I'm talking about. Remember, the documents are a digitized document images (like invoices etc). Can you please tell me for what it can be useful to classify this documents based on the text they contains ?

Comment: This is a really open-ended question! If you're trying to spec out a project, it might work better to come up with a problem first and then go from there. I've added a few more examples, but if you're asking "what should I do with these scanned documents?", then only you (or your boss) can really give you a solid answer.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of uses that spring to mind:

- Spam detection: It may be stretching the definition, but spam and not-spam can be considered topics. You might also classify by emotion, trustworthiness, etc.
- Navigation: Since long before computers existed, libraries have categorized books by topic. It makes them easier to find. The same goes for any document store.
- Further processing. Automatic methods like machine learning often work much better if the domain on which they operate can be narrowed (for instance, machine translation might be tuned for news or for scientific articles).
- Information retrieval: A search engine user might like to filter search results by topic (using a 'faceted search' pattern). It might also be used as a keyword in the inverse index representation of the document (that is, to enrich the flat text).
- Suggested content: Track the topics for the content that a user visits and then suggest new content that matches this 'signature'. You can also use this signature as way to visualize user preferences to interested parties.

Comment: Well, I'm not interested in email spam detection or language translation. You didn't said much about information extraction (which is what I'm interested in) from the documents that I'm talking about. Remember, the documents are a digitized document images (like invoices etc). Can you please tell me for what it can be useful to classify this documents based on the text they contains ?

Comment: If you want more accurate answers than this, you'll need to edit your question to give more information about your task. That the documents are OCR'd images isn't relevant. What _is_ relevant is exactly what kind of documents you're using (give us something more than "invoices etc.") what kind of topics you are thinking of, and most crucially, what you mean by "information extraction". What _kind_ of information are you extracting? What will this information look like? Tell us the specifics of your task.

Comment: I'm exactly asking for which tasks/examples can the classification of such document images be used for !

Comment: shn, This site focuses on "practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face" (from our [faq]), so it's rare for questions of the form "what kinds of questions can this technique answer" to survive here: they are considered too broad to be answerable.